# This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and mean that the local server didn't receive a response from an authoritative server

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, sql-server, webserver

Could you please help me in this ?

**Using webserver :**

I have a Dns server with local database, when any client machine sends DNS name query to DNS Server, it forward that request to authoritative server and after that the client gets the response.
For this process I have used the same code so that my machine can directly communicate with DNS server. The process is working fine for most of the times but from last 2/3 days when my client m/c trying to connect to DNS server I got this exception

> > ::"exception : this is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and mean that the local server didn't receive a response from an authoritative server""

I got this exception 10/12 times a day
Details: there are total 30/40 times I try to connect to DNS server 
__- 10/12 times I get this exception 
__- for remaining it works.